# Regular Expression JS - HTML Parsing on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I need to parse the following URL:

http://m.flickr.com/#/photos/westconn/

I need to get the following details:

1. Image's URL
2. Updated Time
3. Title
4. View details
5. Command Details.

But the contents are displayed using Regular Expression JavaScript.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What are you trying to extract from the page? What have you tried that didn't work properly?

Comment: There's no need to keep adding "If you know the answer, please help." By posting the question, you *are* asking for help and if someone knows the answer, they'll post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the information you need to get, you will definitely find it easier (and more robust) to use the API provided by Flickr. It is well documented here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

In particular, I would point you towards [flickr.people.findByUsername](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.findByUsername.html) and [flickr.people.getPublicPhotos](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getPublicPhotos.html).

There are several open-source libraries for interacting with the API, including [one written in Objective-C](http://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: use a UIWebView, load the URL in it, and use JavaScript to query the DOM and get the data you need.

Long answer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html